# Gauss-Boaga to WGS84

Tags: php, gis, wgs84

I'm trying to convert some coordinates from Gauss-Boaga to WGS84. Here's what I've done (PHP):

```
function gaussToLatLng($Eutm, $Nutm){
    // parametri che dipendono dal fuso ovest
    $l0 = 9;

    $fraz = $Nutm/111092.0821;

    echo "$fraz ";

    $A= $fraz + 
        (0.1449300705 * sin(deg2rad(2*$fraz))) + 
        (0.0002138508 * sin(deg2rad(4*$fraz))) + 
        (0.0000004322 * sin(deg2rad(6*$fraz)));

    $v = sqrt(1 + (0.0067681702 * cos(deg2rad($A)) * cos(deg2rad($A)) ) );
    $y = $Eutm - 500000;
    $B = rad2deg(atan( ($v * sinh(deg2rad($y/6397376.633)) ) / cos(deg2rad($A))));

    $lng = rad2deg(atan(tan(deg2rad($A)) * cos(deg2rad($v * $B))));

    $lat = $B + $l0;

    echo "A=$A, B=$B \n";

    return array(
        'lat' => $lat,
        'lng' => $lng
    );
}
```

Using as input (1517140, 5036970), I get (9.2271558768758 45.485183518206) while with [this online tool](http://www.geoin.it/coordinate_converter/) I calculated that I should have (9.2189597, 45.4859253) (about 1 Km of difference).

Could you help me spot the error in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved using a PHP library: [proj4php](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proj4php/?source=navbar), using the definition for Gauss Boaga fuso Ovest found [here](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/4685/).

Those guys are awesome!